# handlebars.js - looping over json array to determine if checkbox should be checked

Tags: handlebars.js

I cannot change the data source, I have to use what is being provided.

The data looks like this:
`[
    [190, "some title here", 0, 100, 1, "https://www.somedomainhere.com", "", 8]
 ]`

The `1` after the value 100 can be 1, 2, or 3. On my side, that relates to 1 of 3 radio options to be selected.

`{{#each myData}}
<input type="radio" id="radio53" name="activityTypeID" value="1" {{#if_eq 4 1}}checked{{/if_eq}}>
<input type="radio" id="radio54" name="activityTypeID" value="3" {{#if_eq 4 3}}checked{{/if_eq}}>
<input type="radio" id="percentOfMax" name="activityTypeID" value="2" {{#if_eq 4 2}}checked{{/if_eq}}>{{/each}}`

*I'm attempting to use a helper class but open to other suggestions here*

I don't know how to evaluate the `4` using handlebars and that is where I am stuck at. If a just use `{{4}}` in my handlebar template, it will display as `1` using the json string I provided at the top of this post. My experience with handlebars.js is very limited but I'm thoroughly enjoying using it and look forward to seeing how to resolve this issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That was much easier than I expected, I simply needed to put `[]` around it as such:

`{{#if_eq [4] 1}}checked{{/if_eq}}`

Nice!

Answer (score 1):

Do these

```
{{#if_eq [4] 1}}checked{{/if_eq}}
```

Comment: honorable mention, just seconds after I posted my solution.